# JFrame not running on Mac

Tags: java, macos

Upon running the project, Java shows up on my dock but doesn't run at all. It stays there for about 5-10 seconds and disappears. Is there something wrong with the code or my Mac?

```
import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class Test extends JFrame {

    public Test() {
        this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        this.setSize(600,600);
        this.setVisible(true);
        this.setResizable(false);
        this.setTitle("Test");
    }
```

Comment: Where is your `main` function? Or where are you doing `new Test()`?

Comment: That's what I needed, was completely unaware. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It has nothing to do with being on a Mac.

Add this to your main function (which could be in `Test.java` or in any other class) in order to create a GUI thread and instantiate your `Test` `JFrame` class.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    javax.swing.SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            new Test();
        }
    });
}
```

Calling `new Test();` is all you need to do, however doing it inside `javax.swing.SwingUtilities.invokeLater` is very important for the future of your application as it allows you do to other things in the background and at the same time, which will remove any visible latency. [This is what Java itself recommends to do.](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/examples/start/HelloWorldSwingProject/src/start/HelloWorldSwing.java)

You will need to `import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;` or just do `import javax.swing.*;`.

Answer (score -1):

You need to call somewhere the instance of test in order to work..

```
public class Test extends JFrame {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -2949102464273156555L;

    public Test() {
    this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    this.setSize(600, 600);
    this.setVisible(true);
    this.setResizable(false);
    this.setTitle("Test");
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        javax.swing.SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
               new Test();
            }
         });
      }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks! But what is the

Comment: private static final long serialVersionUID = -2949102464273156555L; for?

Comment: JFrame is a serializable object, so it is a good practice to give the class a serialVersionUID,...

Comment: for the sake of the test you can just remove it and ignore the warnings in the IDE